# Set alarm for selected data and time

Tags: java, android

I finished my code with picker class.
I would like to run the alarm at the time selected by date and time picker.
I do not know what classes and methods I need to code to run an alarm over this selected time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                setAlarm(calSet);
            }};

        private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "***\n");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
```

Try this